# find closest clusters of colors in a numpy array from an image file

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, scikit-image

**Current state**

- I have a numpy array of shape `(900, 1800, 3)` that has been made from an image file.
- That's one array element per pixel: 900 px high, 1800 px wide, and 3 channels (R, G, B) per pixel represented in the array.
- There are only a small number (3-20) unique RGB colors in the images being parsed, so there are only very few different RGB value combinations represented in the array.

**Goal**

- Identify the smallest circular areas in the image that contains `n` number of unique colors, where `n` will always be less than or equal to the number of unique colors in the image.
- Return top `y` (by count or pct) of the smallest areas.
- A 'result' could simply be the x,y value of the center pixel of an identified circular area and its radius.
- I *do* plan to draw a circle around each area, but this question is about the best approach for first identifying the top smallest areas.

**The Catch/Caveat**

The images are actually flattened projections of spheres.  That means that a pixel at the right edge of the image is actually adjacent to a pixel on the left edge, and similarly for top and bottom pixels.  The solution must account for this as it is parsing pixels to identify closest pixels with other colors.  **EDIT:** this part may be answered in comments below

**The Question**

My initial approach is to simply parse pixel by pixel and brute force the problem with handrolled x/y coordinate math: take a pixel, work outwards until we hit `n` colors, score that pixel for how many steps outward it took, next pixel.  Keep a top `y` dict that gets re-evaluated after each pixel, adding any pixels that make top `y`, and dumping any that get pushed out.  Return that dict as the output.

I know that many python libs like `scipy`, `scikit-image`, and maybe others like to work with images as numpy arrays.  I'm *sure* there is a method/approach that is smarter and leverages a library or some kind of clustering algo instead of brute forcing it, but I'm not familiar enough with the space to know intuitively what methods and libs to consider.  The question: **What is the pseudocode for a good method/lib to do this the right way?**

Comment: In terms of libraries, take a look at OpenCV, they have pretty good Python bindings. There is even a specific algorithm for circles: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html

Comment: Numpy has a `roll()` function that could enable you to make left and right or top and bottom edges actually adjacent... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html

Comment: Mark Setchell that will be very handy, thank you.